# How to list local-variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, local-variables

```
def method
  a = 3
  b = 4

  some_method_that_gives # [a, b] 
end
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> [local_variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables)

It outputs array of symbols, presenting variables. In your case: `[:a, :b]`

Comment: Can't believe I didn't find it before. Thanks!

Comment: Some versions of Ruby output an array of strings instead of an array of symbols. Ruby 2.0 and 1.9 use symbols, but Ruby 1.8.7 used strings.

Answer (score 7):

`local_variables` lists local variables but it lists them before they are defined. See this:

```
p local_variables
a = 1
p local_variables
```

this outputs

```
[:a]
[:a]
```

which may not be what you expect. Contrast with `defined?`

```
p defined? a
a = 1
p defined? a
```

which outputs the more anticipated

```
nil
"local-variable"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for the list with their values:

```rb
variables = self.local_variables.each_with_object({}) { |key, hash| hash[key] = eval(key.to_s) }
```