# Calling a lambda from another lambda. Why does the order matter?

Tags: ruby, lambda, scope

It's possible to call a lambda from another lambda:

```
first   = -> { 'Ok' }
second  = -> { first.call }
puts second.call
# => 'Ok'
```

but when the order is reversed:

```
first  = -> { second.call }
second = -> { 'Ok' }
puts first.call
```

the code fails with a `NameError`:

```
lambda_order.rb:1:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `second' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  send
    from lambda_order.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

even though `:second` seems to be a local variable inside the scope of `first`:

```
first  = -> { local_variables }
second = -> { 'Ok' }
p first.call
# => [:first, :second]
```

I only use lambdas for [golfing purposes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173059/65905) so I'm not sure what's going on with the scope. Replacing `second` by a method or a constant lambda fixes the `NameError`. It seems related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133969/ruby-lambda-context) but in my case, both lambdas are defined in `main`.

Could you please explain?

Comment: This seems to explain it: "Proc bodies have a lexical scope like functions in Lisp and JavaScript, meaning that when Ruby encounters a free variable inside a proc body, its value is resolved within the context the proc was defined. This is what makes closures possible." ([Source](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2006/12/of_closures_met_1.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
first  = -> { defined? second }
second = -> { 'Ok' }
p first.call
```

results nil => The variable "second" is not defined in the lambda "first".

```
first  = -> { binding.receiver }
second = -> { 'Ok' }
p first.call
```

results main => This means that it uses the current binding of main and thus the variable "second" is defined **only** in the [binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html).

```
first  = -> { binding.local_variable_get(:second).call }
second = -> { 'Ok' }
p first.call
```

results "Ok". That's why the code also prints "Ok" when I ask for the content of the variable "second" of the binding.

*Summary:* The variable "second" is not defined in the lambda "first". The variable "second" is only defined in the [binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html). Therefore, the output of "local_variables" also returns "second" because the information is retrieved from the binding.

I also learned something myself. I hope I could help you!

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It seems to be the case. I guess the question then becomes how does `defined?` check if a local variable has been set. Also, is it possible to list the local variables which are defined inside a lambda?

Comment: @EricDuminil [defined?](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) is a keyword, it checks if an object is defined and if so, it returns the type of the object. In this case, "second" is not defined in lambda, so nil returns. defined? recognizes a defined variable because it is initialized. To output all variable names there are "local_variables", but in this case we would have the problemm described above. I can not imagine how one can output all defined variables in a lambda.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that `local_variables lists local variables but it lists them before they are defined` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21800871/6419007

Answer (score 4):

When a lambda/proc is created its content isn't executed, however on creation the lambda/proc itself is bound to the set of local variables currently in scope.

In your failing example

> ```
> first  = -> { second.call }
> second = -> { 'Ok' }
> puts first.call
> ```

Since `second` is not defined before the creation of the `first` lambda the variable is not passed as part of the [*Binding*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html) for `first`.

However, simply defining `second` before the creation of `first` resolves this issue.

```
second = nil
first  = -> { second.call }
second = -> { 'Ok' }
puts first.call
# OK
#=> nil
```

The [`Proc::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Proc.html#method-c-new) documentation says the following:

> Creates a new `Proc` object, bound to the current context. `Proc::new` may
>   be called without a block only within a method with an attached block,
>   in which case that block is converted to the `Proc` object.

Combine the above with the [*Binding*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html) documentation. Keeping in mind that the binding is bound to lambda/proc on creation (not when called):

> Objects of class `Binding` encapsulate the execution context at some
>   particular place in the code and retain this context for future use.
>   The variables, methods, value of `self`, and possibly an iterator block
>   that can be accessed in this context are all retained. Binding objects
>   can be created using `Kernel#binding`, and are made available to the
>   callback of `Kernel#set_trace_func`.

I hope this clears things up a little.